# Can't set arguments to a view for displaying all data

Tags: views, 8

I use

```
$view = views_embed_view('export_emargement','page_1',$journee,$region,$produit);
```

it works well, but If I don't want to specify $region the view does'nt works.

Im my view admin if I set argument like this 797/62/24 it works

If I try 797/all/24 it works too!every data are displayed

In my code i try this, but it can't be parsed

```
$args = array($journee.',"all",'.$produit);
or
$args = array($journee.',all,'.$produit);
$view = views_embed_view('export_emargement','page_1',$args);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$args` is an array that expects each field's contextual values to be passed in separately.

i think `$args = array($journee, "all", $produit);` ought to work.

you should only concatenate arguments into a string if its a multi-value single field situation and then I believe you join with '+' not commas.

#### EDIT

I missed what you were asking, if you have a contextual filter that is optional inside the view you can configure what happens when no value is provided (pick "display all results").

[image: configuration form for contextual filter]

then when calling the view

as far as skipping an argument `'all'` - the easiest way would be to move the order of the contextual filters so that the one that is allowed to be "empty" is last.

then instead of calling

```
$view = views_embed_view('export_emargement','page_1',$journee,$region,$produit);
```

call

```
$view = views_embed_view('export_emargement', 'page_1', $journee, $produit, $region);
```

or

```
$view = views_embed_view('export_emargement', 'page_1', $journee, $produit);
```

depending on if the user has selected a region

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.
I alreday test : $view = views_embed_view('export_emargement','page_1', $arg1, $arg2, $arg3); it works but if I need all values I need to use $view = views_embed_view('export_emargement','page_1', $arg1, 'all', $arg3); and this one doesn't work..

Comment: OK, it works when I move the argument "region" at the end, but sometimes $produit is null and region is set, so I find a solution by creating different pages and I call her depending on the arguments values...